# Zombie Connections to MySQL using c3p0 with tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling, c3p0

I'm using c3p0 to manage my Database Connections to MySQL.
The problem is that some connections are being hold forever. I have a limit of 1000 connections, but for some unknown reason, there are 1200 open connections. To investigate it, I do this command in the tomcat server shell:

`netstat -n |grep 3306|grep ESTABILISHED|wc -l`

and it returns 1200

here is the c3p0 configuration in `context.xml`

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/xxxx" auth="Container"
          user="xxxxxx"
          password="xxxxx"
          driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          jdbcUrl ="jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/xxx"
          factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
          type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          maxPoolSize="1000"
          minPoolSize="200"
          numHelperThreads="10"
          acquireIncrement="50"
          maxStatementsPerConnection="0"
          idleConnectionTestPeriod="200"
          maxIdleTime = "1000"
          maxIdleTimeExcessConnections = "180"
          maxStatements="200"
          unreturnedConnectionTimeout="10"
          debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces="true"
          />
```

How is it possible to have 1200 established connections if the pool max size is 1000?
My MySQL server is configured with

```
interactive_timeout 28800
wait_timeout    1300
```

OBS: I'm not using hibernate in this application (just in a few classes). Most of the connections are made via pure JDBC code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities.

The most likely is that you have placed this Resource element in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` That file provides the default context.xml for every web application. Therefore, if you have six web applications you will have six connection pools. Since the minimum poll size is 200, there will be a minimum of 200*6=1200 connections opened to the database.

The other possibility is that the web application has been reloaded. You should get a new connection pool and the old one will be GC'd. However, if you have a memory leak on reload (very easy to do without realising) it may keep the connection pool, along with its open connections, in memory increasing your total connections.

To put the definitions in `server.xml`:

```
<Server>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
     <Resource name="jdbc/xxxx">...</Resource>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
</Server>
```

and this in `context.xml`:

```
  <ResourceLink name="jdbc/xxxx"
      global="jdbc/xxxx"
      type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" />
```

Comment: I placed the resource in the server.xml, but it is not reachable via application. How to do it?

Comment: Resources defined in server.xml are <a href="http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Global_configuration">global resources</a> and need to be linked via a RsourceLink to an individual context.

Comment: After moving the logic to server.xml, I still have the situation where the number of connections is bigger than the maximum in pool. I think that, for some reason, the pool has a BUG... Any idea?

Comment: Seems unlikely but possible. A switch to Tomcat's built in connection pool would be one way to determine if c3p0 has a bug.

Comment: Actually I moved from dbcp to c3p0 for performance reasons. I think I discovered the BUG: my website has a lot of accesses. The problem occurs when I put the tomcat machine in the Load Balance while tomcat is starting up. In this moment, I think for some race conditioning reason, c3p0 looses control of it own connections when a lot of request comes to it while it is still building the connection pool. Just a guess, but when I wait some seconds after tomcat startup to put it into the load balance, the problem does not occurs anymore