# Unable to get JDBC connection but only 10% of available connections are being used

Tags: hibernate, playframework, database-connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

Here is exception I am getting

[image]

This is the configuration I am using in my c3p0

```
<property name="acquireIncrement">5</property>
        <property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout">2000</property>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize">5</property>
        <property name="maxIdleTime">18000</property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize">500</property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">5</property>
        <property name="maxStatements">20</property>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
        <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">60</property>
        <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
```

Screenshot of my current connection pool situation is below:

[image]
You can see in Image only 27 connections are currently present in connection pool, while my maxPoolSize is 500, still I am unable to make more connections.

Can someone figure it out while I am getting this exception?

Comment: Are you closing your connections when you are done with them? That is what returns them to the connection pool.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I am closing all connections. But still If I were not closing, I had 473 connections remaining before crossing the MaxPoolSize limit.

Comment: Is that all stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the checkoutTimeout value to a higher value like 10000 (10 secs) or 30000 (30 seconds). By design c3p0 pool manager will try to first establish connections to DB then add those connection objects to the pool till it reaches to a higher value (e.g. - 30 till 200) and only after that will give DB connections to the waiting http threads in the application. In the meantime if it takes more than 2 seconds for the http thread to get a connection object then it will throw timeout error - "An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out" and return.